# How to hide subcategories from menu in wordpress and keep only categories?

Tags: php, wordpress, web, elementor

I have web site, but there is menu where shown categories and subcategories. I need to hide subcategories. i suppose, here i need to change php code or change theme.

P.s. I use envo marketplace theme

Here is code of this menu:

https://github.com/PieceOfNachos/Stackoverflow/blob/main/wp-menu1.php

Comment: Just go to Appearance > Menus select the menu you want to edit and remove sub elements ? https://wordpress.org/support/article/appearance-menus-screen/

Comment: There is no menu which i wanna change, i cant changed it in wp settings, it needs to be changed by changing php code in theme

Comment: What you have provided its just a nav walker. Here is the documenation where you should have menu that will use this nav walker - https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker . Nav walker just tells if there are sub menu items make em dropdown or w/e

Comment: Ask your theme author about this since its premium theme and we dont have access to theme code.

Comment: In your theme find something like this - https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker#usage where edit 'depth' => 2, // 1 = no dropdowns, 2 = with dropdowns. If you dont use child theme keep in mind next update you have to edit it again.

Comment: Thank you guys, ou both were close to truth. In this case the problem is that subcategories and categories menu were hidden in wp panel, i just made it visible and changed it by myself. Thanks!